# Flux doesn't emit elments

Tags: flux, project-reactor

I playing around with Reactor's flux api. I'm already familiar with RxJava so I wanted to test Reactor's Flux.
I don't understand why I always receives 0's in the following code:

```
Flux.create(e -> {
        long current = 1;
        while (!e.isCancelled()) {
            e.next(current);
            current *= 2;
        }
    })
        .subscribe(l -> System.out.println("Got " + l + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName()), e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "!!!!"), () -> System.out.println("finished"));
```

When I ran the code I get infinite lines showing
"Got 0 on main"

Answer (score 0):

You have got Long overflow. Change your while block to

```
while (!e.isCancelled()) {
    if (current < 0) {
        e.complete();
    } else {
        e.next(current);
        current *= 2;
    }
}
```